# Upgrade angular CLI to 8

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I have encountered the following errors when updating the version of `Angular Cli to 8`.

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\AGT\\Desktop\\central8\\client".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\AGT\\Desktop\\central8\\client".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:151:11)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:31:40)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\AGT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:135:55)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check this https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then in your Local project package:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm i 
ng update --all --force
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Your app has now been upgrade to the latest version

Answer (score 4):

If you are upgrading to Angular 8, you should ensure your Angular packages are safely [updated](https://angular.io/cli/update#ng-update) to the current stable version by running the following command

```
ng update
```

Otherwise, you can try to manually update the `@angular/cli` and core framework package manually.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Alternatively, you can directly use npm to install/update it.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

The step-by-step Angular upgrade guide can be found [here](https://update.angular.io/).