# Error while migrating from Angular 7 to Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ivy

I have followed the second answer of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373422/upgrade-angular-cli-to-8) and successfully migrated to Angular 9. Now I am facing the following issue in browser console while running the project.

[image: Error]

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.4",
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.4",
    "@types/underscore": "1.9.4",
    "angular-highcharts": "^9.0.2",
    "angular2-jwt": "*",
    "bootstrap": "4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "core-js": "3.6.4",
    "font-awesome": "*",
    "http-client": "*",
    "http-headers": "*",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "tether": "1.4.7",
    "underscore": "^1.9.2",
    "vm": "*",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.1",
    "concurrently": "5.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "tslint": "6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

**Version**

[image]

This code was working fine with Angular 7. Please help me out.

Comment: You can check the update steps here: https://update.angular.io/#7.0:9.0 Before migrating from v7.x to v9.x, Angular first you need to update to v8.x.

Comment: Do you mean that I just jumped from 7 to 9 ?

Comment: The thread you followed suggests direct update to v8.x. If you've updated as suggested in @malbarmavi's answer below, then you went through from 7 to 8 to 9. But if not, then it means you skipped v8.x. Also, I strongly recommend you to follow the official update guide that I shared in the previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

first update to the final release of Angular 8 like this

```
ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
```

the update to version 9

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

check this [How to update to version 9](https://blog.angular.io/version-9-of-angular-now-available-project-ivy-has-arrived-23c97b63cfa3)